# SortDescriptions cleared by INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm, collections, binding

I'm seeing my ICollectionView.SortDescriptions list cleared when I fire my view model's INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event, messing the sorting in my DataGrid.

I have a DataGrid bound to a `People` property of my view model:

```
        <DataGrid Margin="23,17,21,66" x:Name="dataGrid1" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" Background="DarkGray" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=People}" 
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            Loaded="DataGrid1_OnLoaded"
            SelectionMode="Single"
         >
```

The `People` property just returns a list of `Person` objects:

```
    public IEnumerable<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (Tuple<string, string, bool> personData in repository.PersonData)
            {
                yield return new Person()
                {
                    FirstName = personData.Item1,
                    LastName = personData.Item2,
                    Male = personData.Item3,
                    Index = ++index
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

I add a SortDescription to the CollectionView of my DataGrid:

```
    private void DataGrid1_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do sorting
        ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid1.ItemsSource);
        SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("LastName", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        cv.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        cv.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
    }
```

Finally, I have a button that adds a `Person` object to the `People`list in my ViewModel:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel vm = dataGrid1.DataContext as ViewModel;
        Person addPerson = new Person() { FirstName = "Greg", LastName = "Quick", Male = true };
        ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid1.ItemsSource);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Before add: Number of SortDescriptions = {0}", cv.SortDescriptions.Count));
        vm.AddPerson(addPerson);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("After add: Number of SortDescriptions = {0}", cv.SortDescriptions.Count));
        //cv.Refresh();

    }
```

and:

```
public void AddPerson(Person person)
{
    repository.PersonData.Add(new Tuple<string,string,bool>(person.FirstName, person.LastName, person.Male));
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("People"));
}
```

But apparently the firing of PropertyChanged clears the SortDescriptions in the CollectionView, as can be seen in the WriteLine's.  Of course, this messes up the sorting in the DataGrid.

I have workarounds, such as adding the SortDescription back in.  But I was wondering if this was expected behavior, of if there was a way to keep the SortDescription from being removed in the first place.

Comment: If i remember correctly you can just create your own collection view and bind to that, in this case the `DataGrid` will not automatically create collection view every time the source changes. Refreshing the list might be a pain though. Personally i would recommend using `INotifyCollectionChanged` and not fire a change for the property itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `People` an `ObservableCollection<Person>`.

Then when a new `Person` is created, just add it to `People` and let the `ObservableCollection` handle the notifications. Create the `SortDescriptions` the same way you're doing now. If you're not replacing `People` with a new object, `SortDescriptions` shouldn't change. At least it's not changing for me in the test code I whipped up.

In WPF, the canonical way to expose a changing collection of objects to a view is `ObservableCollection`.

ViewModel. Note that I set `People` in the constructor and keep the same `ObservableCollection` instance from there on in. I add stuff to it, I could remove stuff from it, but it's still the same collection instance.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Dobbs", Male = true },
            new Person { FirstName = "Hal", LastName = "Lindsey", Male = true },
            new Person { FirstName = "Alexander", LastName = "The Great", Male = true },
            new Person { FirstName = "Boris", LastName = "Karloff", Male = true },
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; private set; }
}
```

Code behind and XAML are the same as yours, for all practical purposes

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (DataContext as ViewModel).People.Add(new Person
    {
        FirstName = "Fred",
        LastName = "Flintstone",
        Male = true
    });
}
```

When I click the button, Fred pops up second in the list, between Dobbs and Karloff.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It does in fact work for me.  I am still looking for something where the data is stored in another object: think a database, which my Repository class was simulating, and which is what I'm dealing with in the real app that this example was modeling.  Perhaps there's a canonical way to have an ObservableCollection wrapper around an IEnumerable.  Of course, I'm still hoping someone can explain why the SortDescriptions in the CollectionView are being cleared.

Comment: @GregArzoomanian If you insist on reinventing the wheel, implement INotifyCollectionChanged on your own class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 -- but I work on a DB application in WPF for a living, and the way it's intended to be done in WPF is the way I described. You save to the DB too, of course, but this is by far the least painful way to put the stuff in the UI. I've been down this road. You're signing up for a lot of bugs, pain, and wasted time.

Comment: @GregArzoomanian "Pain and Wasted Time" could be the title of my WPF memoirs. RohitVats below has a great answer btw -- on exactly how the problem with your original code came about.

Answer (score 4):

Scenario you are encountering is completely as expected because you are re-binding ItemsSource on addition of person object. Even if you don't add Person object and simply raise the property changed event for Person object you will see the same behaviour.

### Some reasoning behind the above statement:

Whenever we bind an ItemsSource of UI element, WPF internally creates object of ICollectionView over source collection and bind ItemsSource with it. It can be ListCollectionView, EnumerableCollectionView or BindingListCollectionView depending on type of interface implemented by source collection *(In your case it will be EnumerableCollectionView because People is IEnumerbale)*.

That being said, **whenever ItemsSource is recreated, WPF will recreate ICollectionView object as well** (which obviously won't have SortDescriptions set earlier on previous object). You can verify that by this code sample:

```
ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource);
vm.AddObject(person);
ICollectionView cv1 = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource);
bool areEqual = cv == cv1; // This will output false.
```

Now, you might have question:

> If new CollectionView object is created then why SortDescriptions is removed
>   from old collectionView object?

On ItemsSource change event, datagrid clears its SortDescriptions whenever ItemsSource is changed. If you look into dataGrid code via reflector, this is what you get:

```
private static object OnCoerceItemsSourceProperty(DependencyObject d, object baseValue) 
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)d; 
    if (baseValue != dataGrid._cachedItemsSource && dataGrid._cachedItemsSource != null)
    {
        dataGrid.ClearSortDescriptionsOnItemsSourceChange();
        // Responsible for clearing Sort Descriptions.
    }
    return baseValue; 
 }
```

So, solution for you problem would be to again set SortDescriptions on collectionView object *(do remember to get it back since old cv object is not binded anymore)* OR ideal solution would be to don't recreate the list again. Use ObservableCollection or add object in the list and call Refresh() on collection view object.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff is really complicated and I don't feel like spending the time to ensure the answer is absolutely what you're looking for, but does the following help?

```
dgrApplications.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(0).SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending
```